# Read file from sftp

Tags: go, sftp

I use github.com/pkg/sftp for work with a sftp server in golang.

I want to download file from sftp server.

For that i need to get bytes of this file and copy it to a local file right?

First i get my file with a OpenFile function :

```
        file, err := sc.OpenFile("/backup/" + serverid + "/" + f.Name())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to open file: %v\n", err)

            return err
        }
        myfiles, err := file.HERE()
        os.WriteFile("/text.txt", myfiles, perm)
        return nil
```

But after i need to get bytes of this file but how i can do that?
What should i enter instead of HERE?

Comment: `*sftp.File` satisfies all the usual file io interfaces, just read it like any other file.

Comment: file.Read() not work @JimB same for ioutil.ReadFile(file)

Comment: What does "not work" mean here? `ioutil.ReadFile` takes a filename argument, not an interface of any sort. The `Read` method works like any other `io.Reader`, and you can read directly, use `io.ReadAll`, `io.Copy`, etc. Read through the examples in the `io` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
myfile, err := io.ReadAll(file)
```

Comment: I think you could also use `io.Copy()` to copy from a Reader to a Writer.